# Use Shift- jis in eclipse

Tags: android, shift-jis

I want to use the Japanese in eclipse with Shift-JIS. But I can't do it. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: **Use UTF8**.  It will save you so many problems.

Comment: Please provide a better explanation of the problem. Where are you in the process? What exactly is the problem? What have you tried so far? More details make it easier for people to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the eclipse.ini config file in the eclipse home folder
2. Add the new  parameter -Dfile.encoding=SJIS
3. Close and Open the eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using UTF-8 as suggested. Not clear what your problem is, but generally: right click the project, select Properties, click Resrouce on the left, and select MS932 (Shift JIS) as the 'Text file encoding'. You need to have a compatible font and a Japanese IME, of course.

Comment: requirements for me , it is used shift-jis and don't use utf-8 .Please help me.

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? Did you set the project encoding to MS932? Can you enter Japanese characters? Do they display incorrectly? On what OS are you trying to do this? You need to provide more information if you want to get any help.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all go to region settings and change country or region to Japan and regional 
   format to Japanese .
2. Open the eclipse.ini config file in the eclipse home folder.
3. Add the new parameter -Dfile.encoding=SJIS.
4. Restart the application(eclipse).